# Would it be feasible to use something like PhantomJS to log in to Instagram.com and make a comment on a photo automatically?

Tags: cookies, selenium, automated-tests, phantomjs, instagram

Would it be feasible to use something like PhantomJS to log in to Instagram.com and make a comment on a photo automatically?

Or, any technology that can be run on a server without human intervention.

Comment: Yes it would be feasible.

Comment: Yes, it would be feasible. However, be aware that doing something like that often is prohibited by the terms of service of most websites.

Comment: It rings alarm bells for me when somebody asks to do questionable activity like this without knowing how first.

Comment: @JimEvans good point. hmm... it's just frustrating because they require whitelisting for their comment create endpoint of their API, and they don't seem to respond to form submissions requesting access. Do you know of any case in which a website has proven the legal efficacy of a terms of use clause such as that?

Comment: This does not appear to violate Instagram's [Terms of Service](http://instagram.com/legal/terms/), which include "_15. You must not create accounts with the Service through unauthorized means, including but not limited to, by using an automated device, script, bot, spider, crawler or scraper._"  The fact that they only restrict automation from creating accounts means you can automate other parts of their site, using a manually-created account.

Comment: @celwell were you able to do this successfully? Or did they whitelist your client id ?

Comment: @phoenixwizard no (didn't pursue it) and no

Answer (score 1):

Intagram API would certainly be a better choice, especially [Comment Endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/).

Comment: To use the comment endpoint has been my deepest desire. Alas, instagram (facebook) must whitelist your Client ID for comment access. This, they have not time to do; though my many pleas and patience.